# Is there something wrong with this XML import?

Tags: xml, wsdl, xsd, suds

I am consuming a WSDL that is causing problems for my SOAP client (Python SUDS). Before developers added `<xs:import>` into the WSDL, my SOAP client was working, but now it chokes my SOAP client.

The odd thing is that some of the namespaces reference a non-existent URL for the namespace. Even though it doesn't resolve, I was able to call SOAP methods when it was working.

My sense is that the import is causing problems. Can anyone verify whether this WSDL snippet looks correct or valid? [This](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Schema-TypeNotFound) page leads me to believe that a `schemaLocation` attribute is necessary but I wouldn't even know what to put in it.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" 
  xmlns:ns="http://sdk.mc.nonexistent.com" xmlns:nsv1="http://v1.sdk.mc.nonexistent.com" 
  xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
  xmlns:mcxsv1="http://v1.sdk.mc.nonexistent.com/xsd" 
  xmlns:mcxs="http://sdk.mc.nonexistent.com/xsd" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
  targetNamespace="http://sdk.mc.nonexistent.com">

<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sdk.mc.nonexistent.com/xsd">
  ...
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://v1.sdk.mc.nonexistent.com/xsd">
  <xs:import namespace="http://sdk.mc.nonexistent.com/xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="MethodFault_v1">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="faultMessage" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="event" type="mcxs:EventMoref"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="eventData" type="mcxs:EventData"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
...
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the import is the likely source of problems.  Namespaces often consiste of strings that appear URL-like, although they are used simply as unique strings.  Where the URL does actually resolve, it can help with the problem you are having here with pulling in the types defined in the namespace.

The purpose of the import statement is to connect a namespace with the schema file in which the components of the namespace are defined.  The correct format is:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://sdk.mc.nonexistent.com/xsd" schemaLocation="{schema file URL}" />
```

where the schema file URL can be the name of a file in the same location the wsdl, a file system path or some URL accessible through a network.

It is possible to consume a wsdl with references to namespaces without supporting definitions (schemas) if no components within the WSDL consume types those namespaces.  In this case, the EventMoref and EventData types are from the missing schema and without the schema file the WSDL cannot be properly consumed.

If you have access to the service providers, your best bet would be to ask for the location of the missing schema.